# Unable to compile modules on Android kernel: MODPOST 0 modules

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

On a fresh Ubuntu installation, I have installed build-essential package, amongst other packages that I've then used to compile Nvidia driver for my PC. Meaning kernel and module compilation works on the PC.

Now on the same PC, I tried to Cross compile an Android linux kernel, using the Google NDK Toolchain based on gcc 4.4.3.

Compilation proceeds smoothly, however at the end, it gives the following output:

```
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
```

I have done 'make prepare' before invoking 'make menuconfig' and then doing a 'make'.

Note that the same toolchain, on a build server works with the same files cloned from a git repo. In short, same kernel source, same toolchain, builds modules on the server, doesnt build any modules on my PC.

.config has "Loadable modules support" enabled.

```
$cat modules.order 
kernel/drivers/scsi/scsi_wait_scan.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/btlock/btlock.ko
kernel/drivers/net/tun.ko
```

The Makefiles have correct obj-m and obj-$ setup, which is also obvious by the fact that it works on one PC.

I'll be glad to have some insight on why I cant get my PC to compile modules for my Android kernel.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching, I found the answer.

I'm sharing it here because it's almost inconceivable that anyone would think that this is the reason for this issue!

I have GREP_OPTIONS set for providing color automatically, and to number the results. It seems that a the script which builds modules depends on grep, and seems to get messed up.

unsetting the envt variable made it perform modpost successfully.

So the solution is to:

```
GREP_OPTIONS=
```

And remove the setting from the profile and .bashrc scripts.